# Can we have ExtJs components inside a Flex driven page

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, extjs

I am working on a page which mainly consists of Charts and Grids. Thought that Flex would be the best fit with some cool effects. But however, I now feel that ExtJs grid looks better than Flex data grid.

My question is whether there is any possibility / mechanism to embed Ext JS grid into a Flex page. Lets say my main page has a Flex tab panel. In first tab, I would like to see 'Flex Chart' and in second tab I would want to see 'ExtJS grid'.

I would also want to know of any Flex Data grid plugin (if exists), which looks/works just like Ext Js grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this.

Your best bet is to put the extJS grid in an iFrame that sits above the Flex app.  There is a component from drumbeat insight that helps with this.  Or if you Google around, the technique is described in many blogs.

http://www.google.com/search?q=iframe+Flex&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try that out :)